# Code not executed[ListPreference]

Tags: android, listpreference

I have this code to make some treatement when an option from ListPreference is selected:

```
choice = prefs.getString("listPref_kernel", "0");
if (choice == "0") {
            try {
                File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
              File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/jetpack/install");
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "talondev");
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
            }
          catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Excep_ERROR", e.getMessage());
        }
          }
```

Just after this instruction: `if (choice == "0")`

nothing is executed, i put a toast and it's not showen after that instruction but before it yes.
XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="kernel">
 <item>TalonDev</item>
 <item>Semaphore</item>
 <item>SpeedMod</item>
 <item>Galaxian</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="kernel_return">
 <item>0</item>
 <item>1</item>
 <item>2</item>
 <item>3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Any idea please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is truely String instance then try to `if(Integer.valueOf(choice) == 0)`

Comment: Awesome answer, i accept it, it's working now, Thank you very much! But this instruction convert from String to Integer ? Right ?

Comment: Parses all that is in numeric form of integer inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

Either cast to a number, like Nikola pointed out, or do `if("0".equals(choice)) {..}`. String variables cannot be tested for equality with == .

Answer (score 0):

If choice is an integer try `if (choice == 0)`

Comment: No, choice is a String variable, it's the "pointer" of each option in the ListPreference.